# SQL-Server - Update using inner join with output using inner join too

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am executing the Update_1 but now I need to return the updated row to my users, so I am looking for [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), I tried the Update_2 but is not working.
I really would like to learn how to use OUTPUT, maybe the query for you does not make sense, I translate the queries and shorted it for a better understanding. The basic we need to send to ours clients the updated rows by socket, I would like to make this without execute a select once I already have the updated id in the `inserted`, but I will understand if that is not possible.
Thank you for your help.

Update_1:

```
UPDATE items
SET items.status = 'sold-out'
FROM items
INNER JOIN orderDetail
ON orderDetail.itemId = items.id
WHERE orderDetail.id = 7
```

Update_2:

```
UPDATE items
SET items.status = 'sold-out'
FROM items
INNER JOIN orderDetail
ON orderDetail.itemId = items.id
WHERE orderDetail.id = 7
OUTPUT items.id, items.description, orderDetail.id
FROM items
INNER JOIN orderDetail
ON orderDetail.itemId = items.id
WHERE items.id = inserted.id
```

Answer (score 1):

`OUTPUT` comes immediately after the `SET` clause. You can select from `inserted` or any of the tables mentioned later in the `FROM` clause. It looks like you should just have:

```
UPDATE items
SET items.status = 'sold-out'
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.description, orderDetail.id
FROM items
INNER JOIN orderDetail
ON orderDetail.itemId = items.id
WHERE orderDetail.id = 7
```

You should always consult the syntax for the [whole statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) to see how the various pieces of T-SQL are combined together.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it looks like what you are trying to do isn't going to work. The output statement uses the 'virtual' Inserted and Deleted tables in a way similar to a trigger. One example statement:

```
UPDATE Production.Document  
SET DocumentSummary .WRITE (N'features',28,10)  
OUTPUT deleted.DocumentSummary,   
       inserted.DocumentSummary   
    INTO @MyTableVar  
WHERE Title = N'Front Reflector Bracket Installation';
```

So to do what you want to do would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @temptable table (  
    id int,
    description nvarchar(max));  

UPDATE items
SET items.status = 'sold-out'
FROM items
INNER JOIN orderDetail
ON orderDetail.itemId = items.id
WHERE orderDetail.id = 7
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.description into @temptable

select @temptable.id, @temptable.description, orderdetail.id as orderdetailid
FROM @temptable
INNER JOIN orderDetail
ON orderDetail.itemId = @temptable.id
```

I don't guarantee the above code will compile properly but it gives you an idea. The documentation for the output clause is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017